# Numpy: Substituting for Iterating over Arrays - apply_over_axis

Tags: python, numpy, iteration

It was my understanding that `np.apply_over_axis` was a viable substitution for iterating over  Numpy arrays, as doing it the python-way has bottlenecking that makes things slower; however, it seems that iterating takes ~9% the time `apply_over_axis` does! Piggybacking on this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652785/why-does-numpy-apply-along-axis-seem-to-be-slower-than-python-loop), i decided to do a quick timing for myself:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

def triv():
     ial = [i for i in xrange(100)]

def super(fluous):
     return fluous

>>> print (timeit.timeit("triv()", setup="from __main__ import triv"))
12.3305490909
>>> print (timeit.timeit("np.apply_along_axis(super, 0, np.arange(100))", setup="from __main__ import np, super"))
130.721563921
```

Why is this the case? I don't really know the intricacies of `timeit` that well (or much of anything about `timeit` for that matter), but i think my examples are straightforward enough. I was wondering if anyone found a good workaround, as my real-world problem of iterating over the Cartesian-product of the rows in very large arrays is so slow it's impeding progress.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first place, your example is strange because `apply_over_axis` on a 1D array will just get passed the whole array as a single argument.  It isn't called repeatedly for each element.  For that you'd want `vectorize`.

More generally, though, numpy can't really speed up the application of arbitrary Python functions.  The main advantage of numpy is that it provides its own implementations of lots of mathematical functions, and *those* are fast.  It can't magically take any function and just make it go faster.

In addition, your examples aren't exactly parallel.  You're not calling the same function in both, for one thing.  More specifically, your tests both include creating the input in the timed test -- that is, you create `xrange(100)` and `np.arange(100)` inside the timed part of the test.  So part of what you're measuring is that it's slower to create a Numpy array than to create an `xrange` object:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("np.arange(100)", "import numpy as np")
0.95243776
>>> timeit.timeit("xrange(100)", "import numpy as np")
0.2129926399999995
```

That's roughly a factor of 5 right there.  But in a real application, you'd almost certainly already have the input array created, so this isn't a realistic test.

Using parallel tests, I find that the plain-list version is only about twice as fast:

```
def doNothing(crud):
    return crud

>>> timeit.timeit("np.vectorize(doNothing)(thing)", "import numpy as np; from __main__ import doNothing; thing = np.arange(100)")
49.13036320000003
>>> timeit.timeit("[doNothing(x) for x in thing]", "import numpy as np; from __main__ import doNothing; thing = np.arange(100)")
25.873566400000072
```

Moreover, the numpy version can be substantially faster if what you're applying is a numpy function:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("np.log(thing)", "import numpy as np; import math; from __main__ import doNothing; thing = np.arange(100)+1")
3.2039433600000393
>>> timeit.timeit("[math.log(x) for x in thing]", "import numpy as np; import math; from __main__ import doNothing; thing = np.arange(100)+1")
37.74219519999997
```

The moral of the story is that numpy really is NUMpy -- it's made for doing *numerical* calculations, and it has functions for doing them fast.  It's not just a thing that speeds up all your loops.  If you just have big arrays of objects that you're applying arbitrary functions to, numpy is unlikely to speed up your code, and may even slow it down.  (It can still be very useful for non-numeric data because its facilities for things like complicated indexing into multidimensional arrays are convenient and may be faster than an equivalent Python structure using nested lists or the like.  It's just not useful for speeding up loops over these structures.)

Comment: +1 -- I'd also add that Numpy handles well only fixed-data numerical computations. If you want arbitrary sized integers for example it's better to stick with pure-python, because numpy simply adds some overhead. Also, if the Op wants some speed up in his loops maybe he could try PyPy, which *may* achieve some speed ups.

Comment: @BrenBarn Thanks for this. <The moral of the story is that numpy really is NUMpy...> This is very helpful and gives me a better perspective on how this works.

Comment: +1. Could you list numpy functions that help "complicated indexing into multidimensional arrays" please ? They're scattered about. (New question ? seems too vague)

Comment: @Denis: Mostly by that I didn't mean functions, but direct indexing with `[]` (e.g., the ability to index with an array of booleans).  See [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you go to your numpy installation directory, you can find the python code of `np.apply_along_axis` in the `\ma` subdirectory, in file `extras.py`.

The reason for its sluggishness is that, as it applies your function to 1D slices of your array along the selected axis, it stores the results in an array of `dtype=object` and keeps track of all the return `dtypes`. Once it has finished processing it, it selects the largest `dtype` in the list, and recasts the whole thing before returning it. Which makes it a very robust, and very slow, piece of code. In general, all the [functional programming](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.functional.html) routines in numpy are best avoided: if you need to use them, you may as well do without numpy, because the speed will not be there.

That does not mean that your problem cannot be addressed properly with the standard, quick, numpy functionality. Why don't you post it as a question?

Comment: It would pretty much be a How-do-i-make-this-faster-question. Does that meet the Stackoverflow criteria for questions?

Comment: @NoobSaibot At least half of the questions with the `numpy` tag are of that kind. If you are going to post 100 lines of code, then maybe http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place to ask. But if you can scope your question adequately, I don't think it would be a problem.

Comment: I took your advice and asked the specific speed up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472362/numpy-with-combinatoric-generators-how-does-one-speed-up-combinations). Thanks a million for your help.