# Numpy with Combinatoric generators: How does one speed up Combinations?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, python-itertools

It is my understanding that the [itertools functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) [are written in C](http://blog.behnel.de/index.php?p=163). If i wanted to speed this example code up:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

def combinatorics(LargeArray):
     newArray = np.empty((LargeArray.shape[0],LargeArray.shape[0]))
     for x, y in combinations_with_replacement(xrange(LargeArray.shape[0]), r=2):
         z = LargeArray[x] + LargeArray[y]
         newArray[x, y] = z
     return newArray
```

Since `combinations_with_replacement` is written in C, does that imply that it can't be sped up? Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's true that `combinations_with_replacement` is written in C, which means that you're not likely to speed up the implementation of that part of the code. But most of your code isn't spent on finding the combinations: it's on the `for` loop that does the additions. You really, really, really want to avoid that kind of loop if at all possible when you're using numpy. This version will do almost the same thing, through [the magic of broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
def sums(large_array):
    return large_array.reshape((-1, 1)) + large_array.reshape((1, -1))
```

For example:

```
>>> ary = np.arange(5).astype(float)
>>> np.triu(combinatorics(ary))
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  6.,  7.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  8.]])
>>> np.triu(sums(ary))
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  6.,  7.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  8.]])
```

The difference is that `combinatorics` leaves the lower triangle as random gibberish, where `sums` makes the matrix symmetric. If you really wanted to avoid adding everything twice, you probably could, but I can't think of how to do it off the top of my head.

Oh, and the other difference:

```
>>> big_ary = np.random.random(1000)
>>> %timeit combinatorics(big_ary)
1 loops, best of 3: 482 ms per loop
>>> %timeit sums(big_ary)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: Well, the addition-thing was actually just a dumbed-down example; but i was able to apply your concept to my real-world problem and the difference in speed is like night & day. Thanks a lot!